# net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when send data to the server by using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, authentication, server

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site</title>
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
          $.post("http://35.9.22.104/Token",
          {
            Password: "Super_Secure",
            Username: "Test_User",
            grant_type: "password"
          },
          function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          });
        });
      });
      </script>


      <body>

        <button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

        </body>



</html>
```

Above is my HTML information.I'm trying to implement login functionality by using jQuery,aJAx. What I want to do is to send the data(username,password) to the server(http://35.9.22.104/Token) and the server are expected to return a long string token.

But I got an error "POST http://35.9.22.104/Token net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".
This is the screen shot [image](https://ibb.co/znCsnT4),[headers](https://ibb.co/28JybwM) 
The file "temp3.html" on the image is about my html code above.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? A lot of thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> the url that you are using has no "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header"
>
> so add it in your PHP file
>
> `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
          $.post("http://localhost/api/index.php,
          {
            Password: "Super_Secure",
            Username: "Test_User",
            grant_type: "password"
          },
          function(data,status){
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          });
        });
      });
```

> i have used my local api it works fine